# Applying operation to groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` which I'm splitting in groups by `group = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])` where `a` and `b` are columns. Now I would like to calculate `df["c"].iloc[-1] - df.loc[df['d'].idxmax(), "c"]` on each group and then taking the mean over all groups.

How can I do this? Of course I can loop over all the groups but this is not so elegant.

By the way, with idxmax() I'm getting the index of the first occurence of the maximum. How can I get the index of the **last** occurence instead?

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: Use `df["c"].iloc[-1] - df.loc[df['d'].iloc[::-1].idxmax(), "c"]` trick